# Documenting JSON-RPC endpoints

Tags: java, json, javadoc

We have an extensive Java API that's exposed as JSON-RPC endpoints on our server.  The problem is that the API documentation currently has to be duplicated in Javadoc and JSON-RPC API.  Does anybody know of a tool or a framework that can automate the process of extracting Javadoc to be used for a JSON-RPC API documentation?

Our JSON-RPC framework is very much homegrown.  What I am looking for is anything that will let me parse the javadocs so that I can include the Javadoc snippets in my API docs in a meaningful way.

Comment: Huh... That's why XML/WS/etc is a better choice by default.

Comment: Not sure what you mean, any remote-call framework you choose will face the same problem.  The nice thing about JSON-RPC is the fact that it does link one-to-one to our API, so you can use the same exact JavaDocs.  Plus JSON's data-to-markup ratio is much higher, which is important for a high-performance system.

Comment: The XML technologies have more standards and implementations which cover a lot of aspects, including schema, endpoint descriptors, integration, and they do include documentation. It's easier to make a documented WSDL first (http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/site/reference/html/why-contract-first.html), then generate java interfaces (they take docs from WSDL), then implement them. What's about ratio... I am not very sure if it's true, usually to works via HTTP with gzip compression, so it's hard to tell which one will be better.